# Javascript to Android code

Tags: javascript, android

I need to integrate disqus on Android app:
Below is the script used in webpage, which I want to modify to use in Android:

```
var disqusData = { 
   id: userIdHere,
   username: userName,
   email: userEmail 
};

var disqusStr = JSON.stringify(disqusData);
var message = jQuery.base64.encode(disqusStr);
var result = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(message + " " + 13959635473, "wgEjMAEXMaA8x02fHSHFBFkjsjhdfs"); 
var hexsig = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(result);
var hmac = hexsig;
```

I was able to so partial coding in Android:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObj.put("id", "47424563");
            jsonObj.put("username", "Sweety Bertilla");
            jsonObj.put("email", "sweetyber@yahoo.com");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String disqusStr = jsonObj.toString();
        String message = Base64.encodeToString(disqusStr.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I am not able to construct rest of the script and also I am not sure whatever I have already constructed is correct

Comment: `13959635473` looks like a date

Comment: `wgEjMAEXMaA8x02fHSHFBFkjsjhdfs` looks like a key.

Comment: for HmacSHA1, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026339/how-to-generate-hmac-sha1-signature-in-android

Comment: I tried put the rest in the script but it didn't work..

Comment: `it didn't work` not very helpful information

Comment: For SHA1 I added the code in the script file and tried to launch it but I could see blank screen. I am not sure how to check which script failed. Is there a way to check  it?

Comment: debug it. use for example chrome dev tools to run your script with breakpoints.